# Python program to check if a set of points is at land or at sea

Tags: python, geospatial, matplotlib

I have written a program that divides an geographical area up in cells with size `0.002` degrees longitude by `0.001` degrees latitude, and check every cell whether it's a land area or a sea area. I've done this to effectively to get all the sea area of that area. This is probably insane from a GIS standpoint. Please review my code, call me an insane idiot and help me to get it better.

```
"""Function to iterate with decimal step size"""
def seq(start, end, step):
    assert(step != 0)
    sample_count = abs(end - start) / step
    return itertools.islice(itertools.count(start, step), sample_count)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bottomlat = 70.390829
    toplat = 70.855549
    bottomlong = 27.692793
    toplong =  28.728254
    gridsize = 0.001
    map = Basemap(
    projection="merc",
    resolution = 'h', area_thresh = 0.001,
    llcrnrlon=bottomlong, llcrnrlat=bottomlat,
    urcrnrlon=toplong, urcrnrlat=toplat)
    map.drawcoastlines(color='black')
    """Divide global area into grid cells"""
    for i in seq(bottomlat, toplat, gridsize):
        for j in seq(bottomlong, toplong, gridsize*2):
            lon, lat = map(j,i)
            if not map.is_land(lon,lat):
                plt.scatter(lon,lat, s=0.1, color='c', edgecolors='none')
    plt.show()
```

The ultimate use case is:
I've god millions of lat/long positions from ships. I want to see how large percentage of the sea that has a lat/long position from a ship (cells with a ship position divided by total cell of ocean). So my initial thought was to check each cell if its sea, then perform a check if there is a ship position there.

Answer (score 6):

## Style

Your docstring at the top of the `seq` function should be moved underneath the function signature, like this:

```
def seq(start, end, step):
    """Function to iterate with decimal step size"""
    ...
```

The variable `map`, should be written like this, to improve clarity and readability:

```
map = Basemap(
    projection="merc",
    resolution = 'h', 
    area_thresh = 0.001,
    llcrnrlon=bottomlong, 
    llcrnrlat=bottomlat,
    urcrnrlon=toplong, 
    urcrnrlat=toplat
)
```

All these variables:

```
bottomlat = 70.390829
toplat = 70.855549
bottomlong = 27.692793
toplong =  28.728254
gridsize = 0.001
```

Should be renamed so they appropriately display the fact that they are constants.

```
BOTTOM_LAT = 70.390829
TOP_LAT = 70.855549
BOTTOM_LONG = 27.692793
TOP_LONG =  28.728254
GRID_SIZE = 0.001
```

This comment:

```
"""Divide global area into grid cells"""
```

Should be changed into an inline comment:

```
# Divide global area into grid cells
```

For more help with style, visit [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), Python's official style guide.

---

## Error handling in `seq`

You shouldn't be using `assert` to check if a variable meets certain constraints unless you're doing testing. The proper way would be to do something like this:

```
if step != 0:
    sample_count = abs(end - start) / step
    return itertools.islice(itertools.count(start, step), sample_count)
raise ValueError("Step must not be equal to zero.")
```

---

Comment: Nice answer bui it is more common to reverse the if in your last example

Answer (score 5):

### Superficial issues

`"""Function to iterate…"""` is a docstring, which belongs inside the function definition, not before it.

`"""Divide global area into grid cells"""` should be written as a comment (`# Divide global area into grid cells`).

The way you formatted `map = Basemap(…)` makes it hard to see that it's one statement over five lines.  The four continuation lines should be indented some more.  [PEP 8 says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations) that `resolution='h'` and `area_thresh=0.001` should not have spaces around the equals signs.

### Naming

`map` unfortunately shadows the built-in function with the same name, but I can live with that.

"Longitude" is sometimes shortened to `…lon`, and sometimes to `…long`.

I find `bottomlong` and `toplong` confusing, because they are actually left-right boundaries.

`lon, lat = map(j, i)` is very misleading: those are points in the map coordinate system, not longitude and latitude!  I would consider `i` and `j` to be poor names as well, since they have the connotation of being integers.  The loop should therefore be written as:

```
# Divide global area into grid cells
for lon in seq(minlon, maxlon, 2 * gridsize):
    for lat in seq(minlat, maxlat, gridsize):
        x, y = map(lon, lat)
        if not map.is_land(x, y):
            plt.scatter(x, y, s=0.1, color='c', edgecolors='none')
```

### Just the map

If your goal is just to obtain a nicely colored map of Tanafjord, just use the color-filling functions.

```
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='c')
map.fillcontinents(color='white', lake_color='c')
```

[image: Map of Tanafjord using map.fillcontinents()]

### Sampling

On the other hand, if you are interested in finding the land-vs.-sea ratio using sampling, the most relevant function would be [`maskoceans()`](https://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utilities.html#maskoceans).  Instead of defining `seq()`, you should use [`makegrid()`](https://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utilities.html#makegrid).  You do not need to write any loops at all.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, maskoceans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

bottomlat = 70.390829
toplat = 70.855549
bottomlong = 27.692793
toplong =  28.728254
gridsize = 0.001

map = Basemap(
    projection="merc",
    resolution='h', area_thresh=0.001,
    llcrnrlon=bottomlong, llcrnrlat=bottomlat,
    urcrnrlon=toplong, urcrnrlat=toplat
)

lons, lats, x, y = map.makegrid(int((toplong - bottomlong) / gridsize / 2),
                                int((toplat - bottomlat) / gridsize),
                                returnxy=True)

# Estimate area of sea by sampling
samples = len(lons) * len(lons[0])
ocean = maskoceans(lons, lats, datain=np.arange(samples),
                   resolution='h', grid=1.25)
ocean_samples = np.ma.count_masked(ocean)
print('{0} of {1} points in ocean'.format(ocean_samples, samples))

# Plot the detected sea points
map.drawcoastlines()
map.scatter(x.reshape(samples)[ocean.mask],
            y.reshape(samples)[ocean.mask],
            s=0.1, color='c', edgecolors='none')
plt.show()
```

The result I get:

```
80928 of 239888 points in ocean
```

Unfortunately, as you can see on the plot below, the resolution offered by `maskoceans()` is a bit coarse, even at the highest resolution and smallest grid size available.

[image: Scatter plot of the sampled points]

Strictly speaking, if you are mainly interested in measuring area, it would be better to choose an equal-area projection, though it makes little difference at this zoom level.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful comment. The use case is actually the following:

I've god millions of lat/long positions from ships. I want to see how large percentage of the sea that has a lat/long position from a ship (cells with a ship position divided by total cell of ocean). So my initial thought was to check each cell if its sea, then perform a check if there is a ship position there.